# UIScrollView with subviews taps not being excluded if superview is involved

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

So I am trying to create an interface in which there are essentially 3 levels of views possible.

1. The UIView in charge of deciding the meta-data of new cells
2. The cells themselves
3. The background UIScrollView

Everything is a child of the UIScrollView however 1 is displayed on top of 2.

The goal is that all the cells are draggable and the scroll view is scrollable. However when the scroll view is tapped that should trigger the creation of a new node and thus the appearance of view 1 which will disappear upon the press of a submit button.

I have set up just about everything except I have one huge problem. If I tap on a cell I still get the creation view meaning that the TapGestureRecognizer isnt excluding subviews. So here is roughly what is set up:

```
class Node: UILabel {

    var recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer?
    init() {
        self.isExclusiveTouch = true
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(drag))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer!)
    }

    @objc
    func drag(rec: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        goToPoint(point: rec.location(in: self.superview!))
    }

    public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        var shouldReceive = false
        if let clickedView = touch.view {
            if clickedView == self {
                shouldReceive = true;
            }
        }
        return shouldReceive
    }
}

class NodeCreator: UIView {

    var submit: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.roundedRect)

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

        submit.setTitle("Submit", for: .normal)
        submit.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        submit.addTarget(self, action: #selector(press), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.addSubview(submit)
    }

    @objc func press() {
        if let d = delegate {
            if let t = inputField.text {
                d.created(title: t, pt: storeP)
                self.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
class TaskView: UIScrollView, CreationDelecate{

    func created(title: String, pt: CGPoint) {
        let temp = Node()
        view.addNode(temp, at: pt)
    }

    var tapRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer?

    var nodeSet:[Node] = []
    func addNode(_ n1: Node, at: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero) {
        nodeSet.append(n1)
        n1.goToPoint(point: at)
        self.addSubview(n1)
        self.bringSubviewToFront(n1)

        self.isScrollEnabled = true
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.isExclusiveTouch = false

        self.canCancelContentTouches = false

        if (tapRecognizer == nil) {
            tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap))
            self.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer!)
        }
    }

    @objc func tap(rec: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let pos = rec.location(in: self)
        let creator = NodeCreator(pt: pos)
        creator.delegate = self
        self.addSubview(creator)
    }

    public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        var shouldReceive = false
        if let clickedView = touch.view {
            if clickedView == self {
                shouldReceive = true;
            }
        }
        return shouldReceive
    }
}
```

Why is the TaskView still receiving tap gestures when the Nodes are all exclusive touch.

Comment: Exclusive touch means that when you are touching this particular view, subsequent other touches will not be received by other views. But if you are not touching the view which has exclusive touch property set to true, touching other views will still trigger touch event.

Comment: So what you need to do is, look up UIGestureRecognizerDelegate methods, set delegate and configure in such a way that if touch is received by nodes, it is not received by TaskView

Comment: can you share a zip of code so i can try?

Answer (score 1):

Code does not work because you did not assigned delegate for gesture recognizers. Delegate functions are implemented in Node and TaskView classes. But you did not declared classes as delegates i.e.

```
class TaskView: UIScrollView, CreationDelecate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

Than assign delegate to gesture recognizer:

```
recognizer.delegate = self as! UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

Should work